# get specific element from ruby block, rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block

When performing a block like:

```
<% @user.favoured_user.each do |user| %>

  <li><%= user.name  %></li>

<% end %>
```

With the favoured_user method returning a limit of 5 users, how would I manipulate the block so that even when there are only 3 users available, I could still return 5 li elements?

I'm guessing a helper would come in to play, and maybe the 'first, second, third, etc.' array methods, but I can't think how to write it.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```
<% 5.times do |i| %>
     <li> <%= @user.favoured_user[i].try(:name) %> </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Only one of the five users is being shown, and then 4 blank li elements?

Comment: it should work as it is, is your @user.favoured_user generating an array of 5 ?

Comment: Yes it's generating the array as the method in my first post works fine, the changes you made still return only the first user.

Comment: It does work!!! I was calling the wrong method which was returning one user, Thanks a lot Rishav.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [in_groups_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of)

Like:

```
<% @user.favoured_user.in_groups_of(5).each do |favored_user| %>
  <% favored_user.each do |user| %>
    <li><%= user.try(:name)  %></li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The first 3 users will come through, and the last two entries will be nil

Comment: `in_groups_of` produces an array-of-arrays so won't `user` be an array in your example?

Comment: s/Your/You're/ :) You could also use `in_groups_of(5).first.each` in this case since `favoured_user` is specified to return at most 5.